# swift Show messages group date top screen like telegramx ios

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, telegram

I have a Messaging application, and i want to show message's group date on top of screen and change it on scrolling, like Telegram-x.

like: today, yesterday, march 1, etc

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Create a message Object like this :

```
struct Message {
    user : User // another object containing user info
    time : Date
    message : String?
    photo : UIImage?
}
```

and update your conversation based on last message time.

There is a good tutorial on how to replicate the facebook messenger application [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtEoKixIfG4&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JHGoEg41IJNk9QQ_hPWcyRo) you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you,
but I want show date like the above image and also doing the animate after date changed.

Comment: If you follow that tutorial, you'll learn enough to do that. This question requires a full length tutorial as an answer because you have no code and no where for us to help other than to point you to a place to learn.